# Is it safe to modify filenames in a posix directory loop?

Tags: directory, posix, glob, file-rename, batch-rename

For example there is a directory with 20 files.

```
# mkdir test
# touch test/{11..30}
# ls test
11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
```

And a simple loop to rename the files. It adds a digit 9 in front of every filename.

```
#!/bin/sh

dir='/tmp/test'

for fullpath in "$dir"/* ; do
    filename=${fullpath##*/}
    mv "$fullpath" "${dir}/9${filename}"
done
```

Then run the script.

```
# ./prog.sh
# ls test
911  912  913  914  915  916  917  918  919  920  921  922  923  924  925  926  927  928  929  930
```

In this test, **it is safe** to modify the filenames.

However, if there are more files in the directory, (or in case there are recursive directories,) the first few renames (i.e. 911, 912, 913, ...) might be sorted to the end of the list. Then they might be fed into the loop again, which makes it an infinite loop endlessly adding the prefix digit 9?

I guess it depends on the feature of globbing. If there is a maximum number of item it can take. If it exceeds the maximum, whether it will delay the expansion or not.

Is it always safe to modify filenames in a posix directory loop?

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the question is if globbing continues to expand in a "streaming" fashion. If it did, yeah you could be stuck in an infinite loop if the commands inside of the loop create files that glob can also read.

However, **globbing is expanded once** into a list that is re-used by the `for` loop. According to [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_03), "the list of words" following `in` is expanded to generate a list of items.

```bash
for name [ in [word ... ]]
do
    compound-list
done
```

This:

```bash
for name in ./* ; do ...
```

Is equivalent to this (if "11, 12, 13" are the files found by the globbing pattern):

```bash
for name in "11" "12" "13" ; do ...
```

`For` loops iterate over lists, not a globbing pattern. During normal operation, a globbing pattern just happens to evaluate to a list before the `for` loop could get to it.